# Sorting TWO or more arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to sort two arrays according to their numeric values.For eg

```
apple[]  = [apples, green, 9180, 16.19];
orange[] = [oranges, orange color, 9180, 25.18];
```

I would like to sort it according to the 3rd value in the array i.e 16.19

How will I go about this ?

Note array declaration is for illustrative purposes only.

The result must look like this:

```
String[] apples =     [apples, green, 9180, 16.19];
String[] oranges =    [oranges, orange color, 9180, 25.18];
String[] grapes =     [grapes, green, 9180, 35.16]
String[] strawberry = [strawberries, red, 9180, 45.36]
```

Each line is a **single separate array**. It must be sorted in ascending order according to the last number i.e 16.19, 25.18, 35.16

The array has four fields [apples, green, 9180, 16.19]; Apples: name of the fruit; Green: color of the fruit; 9180: pin code of farm; 16.19: yield of fruits. I must sort these according to the yield of fruits. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I'm having difficulty's understanding what you want. Can you give an example of the result for your example (after the sorting)?

Comment: Do you have your `apple` and `orange` as elements in another array?

Comment: You mean you want to sort not the contents of the arrays, but the arrays themselves? Also don't really understand the question...

Comment: It looks like some sort of inventorying system, and I suspect the OP wants to sort the products by the price in column 4 of the arrays.

Comment: mcfinnigan you're right. I didn't want to confuse members by providing lengthy code, and making them go through it. So tried to make it abstract. Hope it is understandable now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I allowed myself the assumption that you don't have four variables named `oranges`, `apples`, `strawberries` and `grapes`. If you do, put them inside an array before sorting.

Example code to sort an array of arrays of `Comparable`s:

```
class a{

    public static void main(String[]args){

        final int column = 3;
        Comparable[][] a = new Comparable[][]{
            {"oranges", "orange color", 9180, 25.18},
            {"apples", "green", 9180, 16.19},
            {"strawberries", "red", 9180, 45.36},
            {"grapes", "green", 9180, 35.16}
        };

        java.util.Arrays.sort(a, 
            new java.util.Comparator<Comparable[]>(){
                public int compare(Comparable[]a,Comparable[]b){
                    return a[column].compareTo(b[column]);
                }
        });

        for (Comparable[] c : a)
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(c));

    }

}
```

Output:

```
[apples, green, 9180, 16.19]
[oranges, orange color, 9180, 25.18]
[grapes, green, 9180, 35.16]
[strawberries, red, 9180, 45.36]
```

If you want something even more generic, you can define an array comparator which takes the comparison column as a parameter in its constructor (see [updated example](http://ideone.com/mMb81)):

```
class ArrayComparator implements java.util.Comparator<Comparable[]>{
    private int col;
    public ArrayComparator(int col){
        this.col = col;
    }
    public int compare(Comparable[] o1, Comparable[] o2){
        return o1[col].compareTo(o2[col]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can encapsulate your arrays in a class that will implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. This will give you the ability to use whatever comparison strategy you want.

Answer (score 1):

Update after explanation:
I assume you store these arrays in a list or an other array. It this case, you can use `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()`. Since `sort()` can sort only an array whose elements are mutually comparable, you have to implement a `Comparator<Object[]>` that compares the last elements of the arrays and pass it to the sort method. [Example on comparator](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html)

Comment: David the array has four fields [apples, green, 9180, 16.19]; Apples: name of the fruit; Green: color of the fruit; 9180: pin code of farm; 16.19: yield of fruits. I must sort these according to the fruits. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
apple[]  = [apples, green, 9180, 16.19];
orange[] = [oranges, orange color, 9180, 25.18];

Arrays.sort(apple);
Arrays.sort(orange);
```

See here - [how to sort an array](http://www.javadb.com/how-to-sort-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

Question is:

Why do you even encapsulate your Items with attributes as an array? I would prefer a class for encapsulating, called "Fruits". In this class you can implement the Comparable Interface or write a separate Comparator.

After that, you you'll have something like this:

```
LinkedList<Fruits> myFruits;
Collections.sort(myFruits);

// Optional with passed Comparator, myComparator has to implement Comparator
Collections.sort(myFruits, myComparator)
```